# Symfony authentication on oAuth with FOSUserBundle

Tags: facebook, symfony, oauth-2.0, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle to authenticate users from database and now I want add authentication through oAuth services(like Facebook, Twitter and others). How to do this in best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this bundle https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/
It should solve my problem.

Comment: Did that really solve your problem? What you needed, if I didn't get it wrong, is to serve an authorization system implementing OAuth, didn't you? Both FOSFacebookBundle and HWIOAuthBundle help you with the consumption of other providers from your site, and not with the issue of serving an OAuth securing method to your database. Please, could you explain a little further how did you finally manage with all this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the FOS Facebook bundle:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle

They already solved your problem :)

Comment: But I need oauth, not only fb

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for OAuth in Symfony2:

As a client (to authenticate with Facebook, Twitter or Google):

FOSFacebookBundle, FOSTwitterBundle or HWIOAuthBundle

I highly recommend **HWIOAuthBundle**  (https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/), if you're looking for oAuth authenthication only.

And there is a solution for OAuth server:

FOSOAuthServerBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/).